# When installing JQuery, why does my "delete" link break?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application that can create and delete products.  An index page lists all the products.  Next to each product in the list is a delete link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", product, :method => :delete, :title => "Delete" %>
```

This looks like this in the HTML:

```
<a href="/products/104" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete">Delete</a>
```

This has been working fine.

I've reached the point where I want to install JQuery in my application.  I followed the steps available on several web pages (like [this](http://lindsaar.net/2010/5/9/Getting-Rails-3-Edge-with-jQuery-RSpec-and-Cucumber-using-RVM) or [this,](http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3) for example).

After installing JQuery, the above "delete" link breaks.  Instead of processing the `destroy` action in `ProductsController`, Rails attempts to process the `show` action!

My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that web browsers can’t send `DELETE` requests natively, so Rails "fakes" such requests with JavaScript, which is why I had the following line *before* attempting the JQuery install:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Edit: Something during the JQuery install must have made it such that the Javascript used to "fake" the `DELETE` request no longer works, resulting in the `show` action being called.  But what exactly is happening I don't know...

Anyone have any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you put the jQuery driver [file](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src/) inside the `javascripts/` folder? did you also add the two "csrf-*" meta tags in your layout?

Comment: Yes, I did both those things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-check the order that your JavaScript files are being included. Specifically, jQuery must be loaded before the jQuery Rails driver (see the following lines at http://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml#L6-L7):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>
```

(This assumes you replaced the content in `rails.js` with the jQuery driver from http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js).

Comment: Thanks, BinaryMuse.  I tried this and it worked; the order of the JS includes is important.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try including a newer version of jquery,such as 1.4.4:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag   
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js","rails" %>
```