# Rail delete/destroy method won't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Putting `jquery.js` in the `application.html.erb` will disable the destroy/delete functionality.

Following code html code, generated from `<%= link_to 'D', word_path(word), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>`, when clicked,  `show` action ,instead of `destroy` will be called, and no confirmation window anymore.

```
<a href="/words/3" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

Any ideas? Is it a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When installing JQuery, why does my "delete" link break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640702/when-installing-jquery-why-does-my-delete-link-break)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails3 you need to add the following tag in your  to perform a delete

`<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`

As described in the railscast http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to 'D', word_path(word), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>`

For this you dont need to add "word_path" just add

`<%= link_to 'D', word, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>`

and it will work like a charm

Comment: You're right that you can simply place the record there rather than the path, but I don't think that has anything to do with the OP's problem.